# Grouping transactional records into one cell

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables(Companies and Contacts). I need create a list of all of the companies(1 line per company ID) with all of the contacts for each company ID listed in one cell, separated by a line break for each different contact at the company.

I would preferably like this to be done in Access as the tables are from an access BE database, but if it is easier to produce in MSQL then I can do that also.

Thanks for any tips or solutions.

Comment: Is this a report you are asking for?

Comment: No. I need to output the company table as a csv file with the contacts as an additional column.

Comment: With an Access query, you would need to use a user-defined function in VBA, which will not work outside of Access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is for a single column there is a article that you might find interesting

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/

Comment: Thanks for the link. It goes through exactly what i want to do. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL 2005+ would something like this do the trick?

```
;with data as
(
SELECT  'Company1' AS company, 'Contact1' AS contact UNION ALL
SELECT  'Company1' AS company, 'Contact2' AS contact UNION ALL
SELECT  'Company1' AS company, 'Contact3' AS contact UNION ALL
SELECT  'Company1' AS company, 'Contact5' AS contact UNION ALL
SELECT  'Company2' AS company, 'Contact1' AS contact UNION ALL
SELECT  'Company3' AS company, 'Contact1' AS contact
)
SELECT
company
,STUFF((
SELECT ',' + contact
FROM data d2
WHERE d2.company = d1.company
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as contacts
FROM data d1
GROUP BY company
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code. From the link that Kip Real sent, and this code it has definitely put my in the right direction.